# How to get lucene DocumentId in Solr/Solrnet?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I want to get the ID of one lucene Document using SolrNet is it possible if yes then how.

Comment: Actually the problem of highlighting does not work exist in lucene.net as well and in that case we solved it by using fastvectorhighliter, but that require lucene DocumentID..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://osdir.com/ml/solr-user.lucene.apache.org/2010-01/msg01218.html

> Internal doc ids are generally not exposed to the end user [in Solr] and shouldn't 
>   be trusted 99% of the time

If you're having trouble with the highlighter, this is most likely **not** the way to solve it.

Comment: thanx a lot for saving a lot of time